# Php XML sum and group by product

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I have the next xml, and I need to sum by product category. At the moment I have achieved to get the sum of all the products, but I need to sum them by product category.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <Result>

    <Record code="198244">
    <AC_LNA ncols="2">
        <row>
        <product>banana</product>
        <qty>1</qty>
        </row>
    </AC_LNA>
    </Record>

    <Record code="198260">
    <AC_LNA ncols="2">
        <row>
        <product>apple</product>
        <qty>7</qty>
        </row>
    </AC_LNA>
    </Record>

    <Record code="198901">
    <AC_LNA ncols="2">
        <row>
        <product>apple</product>
        <qty>3</qty>
        </row>
    </AC_LNA>
    </Record>
    </Result>
```

This is the code which sum all the products together:

```
$xml=new SimpleXMLElement($resp);
$total = 0;
foreach ($xml->Record as $cod) {

foreach ($cod->AC_LNA->row as $lines)
{   
    $qty = $lines->qty; 
    $total += floatval($qty); 
}
}
echo 'Total is: ' . $total.'<br/>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build an array of quantities for the products...

```
$xml=new SimpleXMLElement($resp);
$totals = [];
foreach ($xml->Record as $cod) {

    foreach ($cod->AC_LNA->row as $lines)
    {
        $qty = $lines->qty;
        $product = (string)$lines->product;
        if ( !isset($totals[$product]) ){
            $totals[$product]=0;
        }
        $totals[$product] += floatval($qty);
    }
}
print_r($totals);
```

Comment: One of the things which is often missed is the casting the element to a string when getting things like the product.

Answer (score 0):

you need to store value in array

replace your code with

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($resp);
$total = array();

foreach($xml->Record as $cod)
{
    foreach($cod->AC_LNA->row as $lines)
    {
        $qty = $lines->qty;
        if (isset($total[$lines->product]))
        {
            $total[$lines->product] += floatval($qty);
        }
        else
        {
            $total[$lines->product] = floatval($qty);
        }
    }
}

echo 'Total is: <br/>';
print_r($total);
```